# LDAP authentication doesn't work on Gitea custom image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ldap, bitnami, gitea

I'm developing a Docker infrastructure with Ansible and Docker Compose and I have a problem with the authentication via LDAP on my custom image of Gitea.
The error that i get inside the logs of Gitea when I try to use one of the users that are in the LDAP is:

[image]

Do you think that is a problem of network or is a problem of the LDAP that doesn't find the user?
The restoration of the LDIF backup works as expected because it adds the user that I'm trying to log:

[image]

Also when I create manually a user in Gitea via the graphic interface, in the authentication sources I find ansible-ldap.
What can be the solution to this problem?

This is my configuration:

app.ini (of Gitea)

```
[DEFAULT]
RUN_USER = git
RUN_MODE = prod

...

[database]
PATH = /data/gitea/gitea.db
DB_TYPE = postgres
HOST = db:5432
NAME = gitea
USER = gitea
PASSWD = gitea
LOG_SQL = false

...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gitea/gitea:1.16.8
RUN apk add sudo
RUN chmod 777 /home
COPY entrypoint /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
COPY gitea-cli.sh /usr/bin/gitea-cli.sh
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
```

entrypoint

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
while ! nc -z $GITEA__database__HOST; do sleep 1; done;
chown -R 1000:1000 /data/gitea/conf
if ! [ -f /data/gitea.initialized ]; then
    gitea-cli.sh migrate
    gitea-cli.sh admin auth add-ldap --name ansible-ldap --host 127.0.0.1 --port 1389 --security-protocol unencrypted --user-search-base dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it --admin-filter "(objectClass=giteaAdmin)" --user-filter "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=%s))" --username-attribute uid --firstname-attribute givenName --surname-attribute surname --email-attribute mail --bind-dn cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it --bind-password admin --allow-deactivate-all
    touch /data/gitea.initialized
fi
exec /usr/bin/entrypoint
```

gitea-cli.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Started gitea-cli'
USER=git HOME=/data/git GITEA_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/gitea sudo -E -u git gitea --config /data/gitea/conf/app.ini "$@"
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: gitea
      POSTGRES_USER: gitea
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gitea
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - vcc

  openldap:
    image: bitnami/openldap:2.5
    ports:
      - 1389:1389
      - 1636:1636
    environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: "true"
      LDAP_LOGLEVEL: 4
      LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      LDAP_ROOT: dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it
      LDAP_CUSTOM_LDIF_DIR: /bitnami/openldap/backup
      LDAP_CUSTOM_SCHEMA_FILE: /bitnami/openldap/schema/schema.ldif
    volumes:
      - /data/openldap/:/bitnami/openldap
    networks:
      - vcc

  gitea:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/custom_gitea:51
    restart: always
    hostname: git.localdomain
    build: /data/gitea/custom
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 222:22
    environment:
      USER: git
      USER_UID: 1000
      USER_GID: 1000
      GITEA__database__DB_TYPE: postgres
      GITEA__database__HOST: db:5432
      GITEA__database__NAME: gitea
      GITEA__database__USER: gitea
      GITEA__database__PASSWD: gitea
      GITEA__security__INSTALL_LOCK: "true"
      GITEA__security__SECRET_KEY: XQolFkmSxJWhxkZrkrGbPDbVrEwiZshnzPOY
    volumes:
      - /data/gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /data/gitea/app.ini:/data/gitea/conf/app.ini
    deploy:
      mode: global
    depends_on:
      - db
      - openldap
      - openldap_admin
    networks:
      - vcc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the address 127.0.0.1 in the entrypoint file in --host, changing it to openldap (name of the service in the docker-compose file) worked.